# How to use .addClass to begin animation, with multiple divs and animations

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I have two separate images (.one & .two) and animations (.slide & .rotate) but when I use .addClass they both play the same animation...as if I haven't closed my css and it thinks they're the same?

This is my .js

```
$(".one").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("rotate");
    $(this).css("zIndex", 1);
});

$(".two").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("slide");
    $(this).css("zIndex", 1);
});
```

Am I using 'zIndex function correctly to make the active animation overlap everything else?

Let me know if you want to see my .css document, it's just the animations are quite large.

Comment: Can you place your HTML & css? and better if you can place and running example with fiddle.

Comment: For z-index the syntax should be:  $(this).css("z-index",1);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stay away from toggleClass because it adds an error source of not knowing the state before using it.

You have to set z-index of the other div as well, so they not both z-indexes will be 1 when you have clicked first on .one, then on .two.

```
$(".one").click(function(){
    $(this).addClass("rotate").css("z-index", 1);
    $(".two").removeClass("slide").css("z-index", 0);
});

$(".two").click(function(){
    $(this).addClass("slide").css("z-index", 1);
    $(".one").removeClass("rotate").css("z-index", 0);
});
```

Comment: Okay, thanks for the response. I managed to get my animations working properly now as well.